# Arrow position should be changed to the center of the formula line

Tags: amsmath, fontsize, arrows

I have another problem :) But I think for you experts it shouldn't be that hard.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,amssymb,array,arydshln}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
$a+b\,\underrightarrow{\mathrm{Das ist ein Test.}}\,a+b$
\end{document}
```

I will get following result, after compiling:

[image]

I would like to change the position of the arrow. It should be positioned in the middle of the line. Additionally, it would be great if I could change the fontsize as well. It should be smaller.

Thanks!

Comment: Use `\xrightarrow` instead of `\underrightarrow`. Use `\text` instead of `\mathrm`.

Comment: He did. See above comment.

Comment: Sure @CarLaTeX, I will add an official answer tomorrow. It is too late now at my place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For text in math mode, use `\text{...}`. For single math variables in roman font, `\mathrm{...}` is suitable. Extendible arrows are available via `\xrightarrow[optional below]{above}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,amssymb,array,arydshln}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
$a+b\xrightarrow{\text{Das ist ein Test}}a+b$
\end{document}
```